# Template Literal type equivalent

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, bundler, template-literals

I have an enum like so:

```
export enum ApiFunctions {
  "setHidden" = "HIDE",
  "setReadOnly" = "SET_READ_ONLY",
  "setVisible" = "SHOW",
  "setDescription" = "SET_DESCRIPTION",
  "setName" = "SET_NAME",
  "makeRequest" = "MAKE_REQUEST"
}
```

Earlier today I created a new type from this enum like so:

```
export type ApiActions = Exclude<`${ApiFunctions}`, "MAKE_REQUEST">
```

This type returns all the values of the keys except "MAKE_REQUEST" (SET_DESCRIPTION,....)

The problem is Template literal types were released on ts 4.1 and the current bundler's ts version is 3.9.7 and I can't really update it since it is externally provided.

I have tried replicating this type by doing:

```
export type Something = Exclude<typeof ApiFunctions[keyof typeof ApiFunctions], "MAKE_REQUEST">
```

But this type instead of giving me the actual string value of each key `SET_NAME | SET_DESCRIPTION ...` gives me something in the lines of `ApiFunctions.setName | ApiFunctions.setDescription ...`

Is there a way of achieving exactly the same type created by the template literal on any other way?

Comment: What is the use case here?  It seems strange that you are using these types both as enums and as string literal types; if you pick one use and stick with it you can write your `ApiActions` type in a straightforward way.  [Observe here](https://tsplay.dev/m0yqnW).  Does that work for you, or is there some reason you need `ApiFunctions` to be an enum but for `ApiActions` to be a union of string literals?

Comment: This belongs to a wider company project that I can't really get too much into but basically those API functions belong to an API that we stick into an iframe to trigger some logic when certain events happen on the window. Make request will trigger API calls but. The reason behind the enum is the data structure in the backend but to be honest your proposal makes as much sense if not more than the one we are currently using.

Comment: So do you want me to write that up as an answer?  I think the answer to the question as asked is "no, before TS4.1 there was no way to widen string enum types to their corresponding string literals", but the more useful approach would be either sticking with enums (and seeing the string values as opaque to the TS code) or string literals.  Let me know how I should proceed.

Comment: you can go ahead and add that as an answer since it makes complete sense what you said and despite no being the correct answer, you presented a different solution with valid argumentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, before TypeScript 4.1 there was no programmatic way to widen [string `enum` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) to their corresponding [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).

---

However, you probably shouldn't want to do such a thing (even with TypeScript 4.1 and above) and there might be a better approach.  TypeScript `enum`s are most appropriate for situations where their values are *opaque* to your TypeScript code base.  So other than the `enum` definition itself, your code *should not care* about their specific values.  The only way you should access these values is through the enum.  So always `ApiFunctions.setHidden` and never `"HIDE"`.

That means you should be able to change the values and nothing inside the TypeScript code should break.  Of course, if those values are important to some external system like an API, then communication with that system would no longer work.  But conversely, if the external system changes so that it wants `"CONCEAL"` instead of `"HIDE"`, the only thing you should have to change in your TS code is `setHidden = "CONCEAL"`; you shouldn't need to do a global find-and-replace of the `"HIDE"` string literal with the `"CONCEAL"` literal.

After all, as you've seen, the compiler doesn't make it easy to refer to the literal values of an enum.  It takes the view that `ApiFunctions.setHidden` is *more specific* than `"HIDE"`, and so you can't use a value of type `"HIDE"` where a value of type `ApiFunctions.setHidden` is required.  And fighting with the compiler to produce one from the other is a lot of effort for questionable benefit.  Let enums stay enums, if at all possible.

With that in mind, my suggestion for `ApiActions` would be:

```
export enum ApiFunctions {
  setHidden = "HIDE",
  setReadOnly = "SET_READ_ONLY",
  setVisible = "SHOW",
  setDescription = "SET_DESCRIPTION",
  setName = "SET_NAME",
  makeRequest = "MAKE_REQUEST"
}

export type ApiActions = Exclude<ApiFunctions, ApiFunctions.makeRequest>;
/* type ApiActions = ApiFunctions.setHidden | ApiFunctions.setReadOnly | 
     ApiFunctions.setVisible | ApiFunctions.setDescription | ApiFunctions.setName */
```

---

On the other hand, if your TypeScript code really *does* care about the specific string literal types, then `enum` might not be right for your use case.  Since TypeScript 3.4 introduced [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), it's been pretty easy to get [an enum-like object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums).  It looks like this:

```
export const ApiFunctions = {
  setHidden: "HIDE",
  setReadOnly: "SET_READ_ONLY",
  setVisible: "SHOW",
  setDescription: "SET_DESCRIPTION",
  setName: "SET_NAME",
  makeRequest: "MAKE_REQUEST"
} as const;
```

From this you can programmatically make a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) also called `ApiFunctions`:

```
export type ApiFunctions =
  typeof ApiFunctions[keyof typeof ApiFunctions];
```

These two definitions behave similarly to the enum version of `ApiFunctions`, except now the compiler lets you refer to the values both through the enum and as literal types:

```
export type ApiActions = Exclude<ApiFunctions, "MAKE_REQUEST">;
/* type ApiActions = "SET_NAME" | "HIDE" | "SET_READ_ONLY" | "SHOW" | "SET_DESCRIPTION" */
```

---

Which approach, if any, works better for you depends on your use case.  I tend to avoid `enum`s entirely wherever I can, because they're not part of JavaScript, and they have surprising behavior (especially numeric enums).  But that's personal preference.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgFLIgGwF5oDeooaaksiK6AogJYAuAFjAE4CSD7cAgmDWACuUIiRBkyMAB4IA9qwZoYQkTwR0AYoLDIGdWWDijxEsnBgMAEnQAmN5WgC8aAESX2AERouANKVNo5gwASjAQNgDyYDgAnk6uAMo0ACoA+sE0PB6pEQByADIAmr7+pkEAanRwdABGOOjOLgmWEQDqJSZlFh7wyKx0CHoG8U0pqV4JAMLB7AAKyex5HQGBFrnQDYljuTwAst5+nRJQEADWMKEAjoLwio27PADSNOk0AIoAqjQJyS6laABfMSmaRyBRoBgxBDoNR0Hi6fSGeI0KTIHCCewAHlhWh0Q0MPjQOO0CIMcAAdCdzlcbnAGAA+ADc-wA9AAqCFQmHqeH4ozOYl4xEUoLWOwOAA+RPUuNJhnJQVC4SisTQUsFcpFFkq1Tq6HVMpJfIV3V6-UGiLV0s0RuFJoY61gaDZLOBgLdFHgSFQaAiHC4cFysgYfAEwmMpn+oPkimQZMUGr58WIRzMFjF9jAAC5XO4vMsAoqwpFojEc6M0hksjkCsVDisKlVavVy802gWugwenA+gN8a2xhNpnMFkt64W1hsB2kdvsO8czhcYNdbuWHs9Xp9vr9-gC0BAjHHDAxmUdo+DIdDrbKk45-mRLzBZAAza+2skAbXOMRfnOhv8TYUAF1TyjGQYz-bk4U1ZFUXRLFALJQkXHXF4Mi3H4XCZVkOUfa1eWFEYkhnPZvCtNxPDIqUK1eas8iKFxyLbdomMHb5h3mRZckYl03SBEBQABIA)

Comment: such a detailed answer. Thank you so much for your help jcalz!